# Alternative to large edge standoffs

Tags: screws, mounting

Are there small alternatives to the large edge standoffs used to mount glass and signs such as the one in the picture below that you can grab at a local hardware or crafts store?

[image]

Looking for something to mount a flat piece. The flat piece has no holes and a frame to hold it is not an option. The mounting solution has to be sturdy yet easy to take off or put back (i.e. not things like glue) as well as aesthetically pleasing (i.e. not things like velcro and zip ties).

One solution I could think of was a screw and a bunch of nuts. Though I do not know what type of screw would have such a large head.

Also for scale, the flat piece is about the size and weight of a smart phone (2.25" wide, 3.25" long, 1/8" high). It will be used as a touch display so drilling holes onto it is not an option. The standoff aspect is needed because there are electronics mounted on the back.

Comment: Smart phone. The one above is too big, it's typically used for mounting larger pieces. Smallest variety I could find is 9mm diameter, 25mm height which is too big.

Comment: VTC - This is a shopping question that is not on topic here.

Comment: If you could get more specific to the needs of mounting the flat piece, what functionality you are trying to create, the size and thickness of the flat piece it may allow your question to stand. And then you are likely to get some ideas to achieve your goal in another way.

Comment: Does it have to "stand off", above the mounting surface, like in the picture? Or can it just mount flat to the surface?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it, the standoff is ideal as there are components on the underside that prevent it from laying flush

Comment: @MichaelKaras, I updated the question with the info you recommended. I don't think this qualifies as a shopping question... I'm looking for ideas people with more experience than me might have on how to mount... not necessarily product recommendations just keywords to point me in the right direction.

Comment: @JetBlue - I would not mount a combo LCD display / touch screen by just its corners. There is just too much chance of a stress point at the mounts that could lead to fracture of the glass. I would instead recommend that you search out the types of display/touch modules that come with an integrated plastic frame around them for your application. This may be one possibility: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12725. However for the price you may just be better off just using a fully packaged tablet or smart phone which you equip with the appropriate software.

Comment: Used smart phones can be purchased from eBay for relatively low prices and they come nicely already packaged up.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I'm not mounting directly onto the screen... the screen is attached to a PCB. The PCB does not have mounting holes. But this too much detail as it is... because the question is generic... doesn't matter whether I'm attaching it to a PCB or a piece of wood or a piece of plastic ... looking for general ideas on how to mount a flat piece using standoffs without drilling holes onto said flat piece... Also I never said that the flat piece is a smart phone, I make the comparison only as a quick size/weight reference.

Comment: But you did say that it was going to be "used as a touch display". My SUGGESTION was to consider just using an already packaged solution such as a tablet or smart phone instead of a bare display module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is "mirror clips" or "concealed mirror clips". These can be used to mount flat items to a surface without requiring holes etc in the piece to be fastened in place.

Comment: "Concealed mirror clip" is turning up promising results, thanks!